# Testing Parseval's Theorem with Power Spectral Density

Tags: scipy, signals, signal-processing, fft

Suppose I am finding the power spectral density of data like such:

```
x = winter_data.values #measured at frequency 1Hz
f, Sxx = sp.signal.welch(x1, fs=1, window='hanning', nperseg=N, noverlap = N / 2)
```

I want to test that Parseval's theorem works on these data sets. Since welch returns the power spectral density, should we not have

```
np.trapz(x**2, dx=1)
```

and

```
len(x1)*np.trapz(Sxx, f)
```

equal to eachother? Or is my definition of power spectral density incorrect? (np.trapz() is just used to calculate the integrals). I always thought that power spectral density was defined as

S_xx(f) = (1/T)|X(f)|^2

Currently I am not getting them equal.

Comment: They are approxmatively equal for some test data I made up. The windowing procedure will make them non equal anyway. What error do you have?

Comment: I'm getting 100000 for the np.trapz(x**2, dx=1) and 1000000 for len(x1)*np.trapz(Sxx, f). So abour 10x greater.

Comment: It is possible that the DC componennt is removed by welch. Could you try `np.trapz((x-x.mean())**2, dx=1)`?